# Can Xcode tell me if I forget to include a category implementation in my target?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, linker, objective-c-category

I have a category that I import in a .m thusly:

```
#import "UIView+Additions.h"
```

If I forget to add `UIView+Additions.m` to my target, I won't know until runtime when the runtime can't find my selector. Is there a way to find out at compile time (or probably link time) that I forgot to include a category's implemtation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This macro works!

```
#ifndef HJBObjCCategory_h
#define HJBObjCCategory_h

#define HJBObjCCategoryInterface( c , n ) \
\
extern int c##n##Canary; \
\
__attribute__((constructor)) static void c##n##CanaryCage() { \
    c##n##Canary = 0; \
} \
\
@interface c (n)

#define HJBObjCCategoryImplementation( c , n ) \
\
int c##n##Canary = 0; \
\
@implementation c ( n )

#endif
```

Use it like this:

**UIView+Additions.h**

```
HJBObjCCategoryInterface(UIView, Additions)

- (void)hjb_foo;

@end
```

**UIView+Additions.m**

```
HJBObjCCategoryImplementation(UIView, Additions)

- (void)hjb_foo {
  NSLog(@"foo!");
}

@end
```