# Generate random identifier in C Preprocessor to avoid duplicate linker symbols

Tags: objective-c, c, c-preprocessor, objective-c-category

I'm trying to solve [Can Xcode tell me if I forget to include a category implementation in my target?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17057352/can-xcode-tell-me-if-i-forget-to-include-a-category-implementation-in-my-target), and I came up with the following solution:

**NSObject+Foo.h**

```
extern int volatile canary;
void canaryCage() {
  canary = 0;
}
```

**NSObject+Foo.m**

```
int canary = 0;
```

Now, if I `#import "NSObject+Foo.h"` in a source file, I'll get a linker error if that `NSObject+Foo.m` wasn't also included in my target.

However, every time I `#import "NSObject+Foo.h"` I generate a duplicate `_canaryCage` symbol. I can't use `__COUNTER__` because I only `#import "NSObject+Foo.h"` in implementation files. I need `canaryCage` to be unique across my whole symbol table.

I need something like:

```
#define CONCAT(x, y) x##y
#define CONCAT2(x, y) CONCAT(x, y)
extern int volatile canary;
void CONCAT2(canaryCage, __RANDOM__)() {
  canary = 0;
}
```

This way, if I have source files like:

**Bar.m**

```
#import "NSObject+Foo.h"
```

**Baz.m**

```
#import "NSObject+Foo.h"
```

I'll get symbols like `_canaryCage9572098740753234521` and `_canaryCage549569815492345`, which won't conflict.  I also don't want to enable `--allow-multiple-definition` in `ld` because I want other duplicate symbol definitions to cause an error. I don't want to use `canaryCage` for anything but a marker that I forgot to link a source file whose header I `#import`ed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17079321/9636) was close, but it resulted in `canaryCage` being optimized away because it was dead code.

Solution:

**NSObject+Foo.h**

```
extern int canary;
__attribute__((constructor)) static void canaryCage() {
  canary = 0;
}
```

**NSObject+Foo.m**

```
int canary = 0;
```

Unfortunately, this adds some overhead every time the category is imported, but the overhead is very minimal. If anyone knows a way to prevent `canaryCage` from being stripped, I'll happily mark their answer as correct.

Answer (score 2):

If you make it `static`, each translation unit will get its own copy, and everything else should work the way you want it to - no preprocessor gymnastics required.

```
static void canaryCage()
{
    canary = 0;
}
```

Comment: Now it gets optimized away because there are no uses of `canaryCage`.

Comment: Did you try linking with `-all_load` to force the symbols to resolve even if they get stripped?

Comment: Yes. I think clang is not even compiling the function because it is an unused static function. Thus, category consumers don't get it in their non-global symbols table, which means they don't consume `canary`, which means there is no one to trigger the linker error about it missing.